# Opengl Framebuffer offscreen, flickering

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to render the position of my objects to a texture, to do deffered shading. But when I display the texture to a quad I have some weirds results.

[Flickering result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJckV.png)

I init the FBO with :

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
glGenTextures(3, textureColorbuffer);
//... 
//Position texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer[2]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 2, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer[2], 0);

GLuint rboDepth;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboDepth);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboDepth);

GLuint attachments[3] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2 };
glDrawBuffers(3, attachments);
if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    std::cerr << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!" << std::endl;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Then I draw my different meshes with this shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;
layout (location = 1) out vec4 BrightColor;
layout (location = 2) out vec3 posTexture;


uniform vec4 mainColor;
uniform int BloomEffect;
in vec3 ourPosition;

void main(){
    vec4 color = mainColor;
    posTexture = ourPosition;
    BrightColor = vec4(0,0,0,1);
    FragColor = color;
    }
```

Then I display the texture which contains the position information with this shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 TexCoords;
uniform sampler2D screenTexture;
uniform sampler2D bloomBlur;

uniform vec2 screenSize;
uniform vec2 viewPos;
uniform sampler2D posTexture;

void main(){

vec4 hdrColor = texture(screenTexture, TexCoords);
vec4 bloomColor = texture(bloomBlur, TexCoords);
vec3 pos = texture(posTexture, TexCoords).rgb;
FragColor = vec4(pos.rgb, 1);
}
```

I have no issues of flickering when I send the position to the texture with a vec4 whereas the internal format is GL_RGB. How can I solve this problem ?

EDIT : typo mistake

EDIT precision : The other textures are written correctly, it's only when I use the posTexture that my flickering problem appears.

Comment: Does your shader compile? It uses a variable (`Color`) that I don't see defined anywhere.

Comment: @Reto Koradi Typo mistake, all shaders compile